# Retrieving list of meetings and meeting attendees from AWS SDK for Chime

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the SDK to retrieve a list of meeting IDs (there will only be one) and then a list of attendees in that meeting.

I have the following code:

```java
Amazon.Chime.AmazonChimeClient client = new Amazon.Chime.AmazonChimeClient(accesskey, secretkey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
Amazon.Chime.Model.ListMeetingsRequest meetingrequest = new Amazon.Chime.Model.ListMeetingsRequest();
meetingrequest.MaxResults = 100;
Amazon.Chime.Model.ListMeetingsResponse resp = client.ListMeetings(meetingrequest);
```

The `resp.Meetings.Count` is 0, whether I'm holding a meeting or just having scheduled one. May someone explain what I am doing wrong? Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.